# how to assign XML tag to a string variable

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

i want to assign xml tag contents to string:-

```
String str=
"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PrintLetterBarcodeData uid="s3434343" name="sdsdasdasd" gender="M" yob="1991" co="S/sdsds" street="sdsdsdl605"/>
";
```

but there are few errors.
I am using eclipse.
this tag automatically generated by QR code scanner,hence i can not modify this tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape all the double-quotes:

```
String str="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <PrintLetterBarcodeData uid=\"s3434343\" name=\"sdsdasdasd\" gender=\"M\" yob=\"1991\" co=\"S/sdsds\" street=\"sdsdsdl605\"/>";
```

Comment: i am developing a program, which extracts XML data from QR code, stores in string variable, retrieves ID&name and stores in database.
hence, XML code cant edit manually

Comment: Your question isn't about an XML tag that was read from somewhere at runtime, it's about XML written in a string literal in your source code.  And this answer is telling you how to correctly write string literals with embedded quote characters in Java source code.

Comment: I agree with @Wyzard . When you process something at runtime you don't have these kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

What are the errors?  It is hard to diagnose it without knowing the errors.  However, I can say that you will need a \ character before the quotes inside the XML string.

It would be

```
String str= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><PrintLetterBarcodeData uid=\"s3434343\" name=\"sdsdasdasd\" gender=\"M\" yob=\"1991\" co=\"S/sdsds\" street=\"sdsdsdl605\"/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the values of the data, you should use some kind of xml parser.

since Java 1.6 you can use [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) for this task:

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "PrintLetterBarcodeData" )
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PrintLetterBarcodeData
{
    enum Gender
    {
        M, F
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    String uid;
    @XmlAttribute
    String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    Gender gender;
    @XmlAttribute( name = "yob" )
    int    yearOfBirth;
    @XmlAttribute
    String co;
    @XmlAttribute
    String street;

    // getters/setters omitted for readability, these should be used in production code
}

private static PrintLetterBarcodeData parse( String xml ) throws JAXBException
{
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance( PrintLetterBarcodeData.class ).createUnmarshaller();

    return (PrintLetterBarcodeData) unmarshaller.unmarshal( new StringReader( xml ) );
}

private static void sample() throws JAXBException
{
    String str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <PrintLetterBarcodeData uid=\"s3434343\" name=\"sdsdasdasd\" gender=\"M\" yob=\"1991\" co=\"S/sdsds\" street=\"sdsdsdl605\"/>";

    PrintLetterBarcodeData barcodeData = parse( str );

    System.out.println( barcodeData.uid );
    System.out.println( barcodeData.name );
    System.out.println( barcodeData.gender );
    System.out.println( barcodeData.yearOfBirth );
    System.out.println( barcodeData.co );
    System.out.println( barcodeData.street );
}
```

you can then use it like any normal java object.

Answer (score 0):

How do you put the text into eclipse, pasting from clipboard?
In that case try `Preferences/Java/Editor/Typing/ "Escape text when pasting into a string literal"`.
If you read String from otyher source you can try with `http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html`